# Displaying div if current week-number matches id of div

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a website that shows a new image for every week of the year. I got as far as to be able to get the current week number as a variable, but I am unsure on how to access it in a way that allows me to change the display of said DIV from "none" to "block".

My beginner knowledge tells me that something like this would be the way to go,

JS code.

```
Date.prototype.getWeekNumber = function(){
    var d = new Date(Date.UTC(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), this.getDate()));
    var dayNum = d.getUTCDay() || 7;
    d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 4 - dayNum);
    var yearStart = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(),0,1));
    return Math.ceil((((d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1)/7)
  };


var s = (new Date().getWeekNumber());
var s = document.getElementById(d.getDay());
    s.style.display = (s.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
```

HTML sample.

```
<div class="container" id="8" style="display:none">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h1>Week 8</h1>
          <p>Sample Text</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
          <img src="image.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the display from block to none and vice versa?

Comment: My plan is to have a div for every week of the year. 
And when the week changes I want to change it to block for just that week, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work. I added another image container for testing purposes.

```js
Date.prototype.getWeekNumber = function(){
    var d = new Date(Date.UTC(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), this.getDate()));
    var dayNum = d.getUTCDay() || 7;
    d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 4 - dayNum);
    var yearStart = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(),0,1));
    return Math.ceil((((d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1) / 7)
};

let weekNumber = new Date().getWeekNumber();
document.getElementById(weekNumber).style.display = "block";
```

```html
<div class="container" id="8" style="display:none">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h1>Week 8</h1>
          <p>Sample Text</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
          <img src="image.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container" id="9" style="display:none">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h1>Week 9</h1>
          <p>Sample Text</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
          <img src="image.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Ahh this works perfectly! One quick question, next week it should update the display back to none for week 8 and instead display the next as block? *EDIT: forgot to close out a DIV tag. It works perfectly, that you for your quick and reliable answer!

Comment: Good to hear :)